# jenkins workspace for multi branch project

Tags: jenkins, project, workspace

I'm using Jenkins with multi-branch plugin project. On default settings Jenkins creates a workspace for all new branches as sub-project folder:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname_branchname1_SHA1  
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projectname_branchname2_SHA2  
...
```

If I go to `Project -> Configure -> Advanced Project Option -> Advance -> Use custom workspace` and set a new workspace, Jenkins does not create sub-project folder. It just does git clone to the new workspace. How I can change workspace?

ps: sorry for mistakes english not my native =(